# Routing problem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rails-routing

// see below for update

Error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"conversations", :action=>"reply", :id=>nil, :board_id=>nil}
```

Parameters dump:

```
{"board_id"=>"2",
 "id"=>"3"}
```

Log:

```
Started GET "/boards/2/conversations/3/reply" for 127.0.0.1 at Mon Apr 04 23:40:59 +0200 2011
  Processing by ConversationsController#reply as HTML
  Parameters: {"board_id"=>"2", "id"=>"3"}
  Board Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "boards"."id" FROM "boards" WHERE ("boards"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
  Board Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "boards".* FROM "boards" WHERE ("boards"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Rendered conversations/_reply_form.html.erb (1.3ms)
Rendered conversations/reply.html.erb within layouts/application (9.4ms)
Completed   in 30ms

ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:controller=>"conversations", :action=>"reply", :id=>nil, :board_id=>nil}):
    1: <%= form_for(@comment, :url => reply_board_conversation_url(:board_id=>@board_id, :id=>@conversation_id)) do |f| %>
    2:   <% if @comment.errors.any? %>
    3:     <div id="error_explanation">
    4:       <h2><%= pluralize(@comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this reply from being saved:</h2>
  app/views/conversations/_reply_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_conversations__reply_form_html_erb__999049254_2171331720_2303070'
  app/views/conversations/reply.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_conversations_reply_html_erb___838091718_2171408600_0'

Rendered /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.1ms)
Rendered /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (982.1ms)
Rendered /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (1001.7ms)
```

In my routes.rb, its:

```
  get '/boards/:board_id/conversations/:id/reply' => "conversations#reply", :as => :reply_board_conversation
  post '/boards/:board_id/conversations/:id/reply' => "conversations#save_reply", :as => :reply_board_conversation

  resources :boards do 
    resources :conversations
  end
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

// Update:

Figured out the params. But, now we have a new error.. see output:

```
Started GET "/boards/2/conversations/3/reply" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Apr 05 11:29:52 +0200 2011
  Processing by ConversationsController#reply as HTML
  Parameters: {"board_id"=>"2", "conversation_id"=>"3"}
  Board Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "boards"."id" FROM "boards" WHERE ("boards"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
  Board Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "boards".* FROM "boards" WHERE ("boards"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Rendered conversations/_reply_form.html.erb (4.3ms)
Rendered conversations/reply.html.erb within layouts/application (6.3ms)
Completed   in 26ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class):
    1: <%= form_for(@comment, :url => reply_board_conversation_url(:board_id=>@board.id, :id=>@conversation_id)) do |f| %>
    2:   <% if @comment.errors.any? %>
    3:     <div id="error_explanation">
    4:       <h2><%= pluralize(@comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this reply from being saved:</h2>
  app/views/conversations/_reply_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_conversations__reply_form_html_erb__999049254_2174448800_2303070'
  app/views/conversations/reply.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_conversations_reply_html_erb___838091718_2174498080_0'

Rendered /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.1ms)
Rendered /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (757.4ms)
Rendered /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (774.2ms)
```

Answer (score 1):

The log you provided indicates the @board_id and @conversation_id variables are nil.

Make sure you are actually setting the value of `@board_id` and `@conversation_id` in `ConversationsController`'s reply action.  I suspect you are either populating `board_id` or forgetting to do something like `@board_id = params[:board_id]` altogether.

**Update**
To answer the next part of your question, I am guessing that `@comment` has not been instantiated.  Somewhere in your controller action you should do something like the following:

```
@comment = Comment.new(params[:comment]
```

This should create a comment from any existing form data, or a new comment if there isn't any form data.

Comment: ok, did the job on the params. However, now a new error appears: "undefined method 'model_name' for NilClass:Class" - Any other hints? Thx..

Answer (score 0):

Your `@board_id` and `@conversation_id` variables are both nil, as it says in the error message:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"conversations", 
                  :action=>"reply",
                  :id=>nil,
                  :board_id=>nil
                 }
```

Note the `:id` and `:board_id` parameters here.